# Prevent image in contenteditable div from being dragged to another div

Tags: html, css

I have many divs that are content editable. One of my business rules is that the users can drag images within a div, and retrieve the positions of those images within the div later.

However the exact number of images must be maintained for each div, so I can't let them delete the images or drag them to another div. I'll only ask about the dragging between divs right now.

Here's a jsfiddle page where I have two divs and an image. http://jsfiddle.net/r6Qe4/

What I'm looking to do is prevent the image inside the first div from being dragged to the second div, but still allow it to me moved in the first div.

Hope that makes sense.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to listen to the drag/drop events and inspect what's being dragged, but this doesn't seem quite ready for prime-time.

See:

```
http://codebits.glennjones.net/editing/events-contenteditable.htm
```